# How to trigger Object Lambda Access Point through Virtual-Hosted-Style access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a AWS S3 bucket configured for static web hosting with public access.

I created an Access Point for the bucket, created a Lambda function to provide some basic GET validation and tied the Access Point to the Lambda through the Object Lambda Access Point configuration.  It took a lot of digging because AWS does not make it easy to find but you should be able to access access points through the following website endpoint:

```
https://<ACCESS_POINT_NAME>-<CUSTOMER_ID>.s3-accesspoint.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
```

That should then hopefully trigger the Lambda during any GET request.

However, when I go to my address in a browser I get an XML error with the following message:

```
The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use Signature Version 4.
```

According to the docs (

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-points-restrictions-limitations.html

) only the REST API requires signature verification but then also Access Points do not support anonymous access.

I'm confused by these seemingly conflicting pieces of information.  Why is a website endpoint available but yet not allow anonymous access.  But if accessing the Access Point through the browser is not the REST API, why it is complaining about a signature requirement.

Is my design even possible with a public S3 bucket accessed through an Access Point with a level of control provided through the Lambda?  If so, what configurations are necessary to make this work?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I didn't see where in the doc it says "only the REST API requires signature verification". I see "You must use AWS Signature Version 4 when making requests to an access point using the REST APIs." While it might not be the clearest doc, I don't think you can infer unsigned requests. Also, I presume the 'website endpoint' is available because S3 clients of the Access point need to send their requests to that endpoint as opposed to some generic s3.amazonaws.com or mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com endpoint. That is to say, it's not expressly for static hosting purposes.